# How to convert 03AUG2023:00:00:00.000000 time to this sas format 2006553600

Tags: sas

Ineed to convert below date into sas date
03AUG2023:00:00:00.000000  time to this sas format 2006553600

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Input date and time */
data input_date;
    input date_time $30.;
    datalines;
03AUG2023:00:00:00.000000
;

/* Convert to SAS date and time */
data converted_date;
    set input_date;
    
    /* Define a format for reading the input date */
    informat date_time $30.;

    /* Parse the input date into components */
    day = input(substr(date_time, 1, 2), 2.);
    month = input(substr(date_time, 3, 3), $3.);
    year = input(substr(date_time, 6, 4), 4.);
    hour = input(substr(date_time, 11, 2), 2.);
    minute = input(substr(date_time, 13, 2), 2.);
    second = input(substr(date_time, 16, 2), 2.);
    microseconds = input(substr(date_time, 19), 12.);

    /* Calculate the number of seconds since January 1, 1960 */
    sas_date_seconds = intnx('SECOND', '01JAN1960:00:00:00.000000', dhms(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)) + microseconds / 1e6;
    
    /* Convert to SAS date format */
    sas_date_format = sas_date_seconds / 86400 + 21916;
    
    /* Output the result */
    format sas_date_format datetime21.;
    drop day month year hour minute second microseconds;
run;

/* Display the result */
proc print data=converted_date;
    var date_time sas_date_format;
run;
```